# unable to update certificate(s) with update-ca-certificates

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I'm trying to use `UPDATE-CA-CERTIFICATES(8)` (update-ca-certificates - update /etc/ssl/certs and ca-certificates.crt), yet not getting to desirable state:

```
root@www:~# cd /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
root@www:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates# wget https://ssl-ccp.godaddy.com/repository/gdig2.crt.pem
--2019-02-14 17:36:52--  https://ssl-ccp.godaddy.com/repository/gdig2.crt.pem
Resolving ssl-ccp.godaddy.com (ssl-ccp.godaddy.com)... 173.201.19.14
Connecting to ssl-ccp.godaddy.com (ssl-ccp.godaddy.com)|173.201.19.14|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 
Length: 1728 (1.7K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘gdig2.crt.pem’

gdig2.crt.pem              100%[=====================================>]   1.69K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2019-02-14 17:36:52 (40.2 MB/s) - ‘gdig2.crt.pem’ saved [1728/1728]

root@www:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates# wget https://ssl-ccp.godaddy.com/repository/sfig2.crt.pem
--2019-02-14 17:36:56--  https://ssl-ccp.godaddy.com/repository/sfig2.crt.pem
Resolving ssl-ccp.godaddy.com (ssl-ccp.godaddy.com)... 173.201.19.14
Connecting to ssl-ccp.godaddy.com (ssl-ccp.godaddy.com)|173.201.19.14|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 
Length: 1793 (1.8K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘sfig2.crt.pem’

sfig2.crt.pem              100%[=====================================>]   1.75K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2019-02-14 17:36:56 (43.0 MB/s) - ‘sfig2.crt.pem’ saved [1793/1793]

root@www:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates# update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
root@www:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates#
```

I've ran same thing on yet another Linux host and everything worked like a charm there (same OS & version).

```
root@www:~# cat /etc/debian_version 
9.7
root@www:~# uname -a
Linux www 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@www:~#
```

Please advise.

Comment: What OS? What version?

Comment: @bodgit sorry for not including that with my initial question (updated)

Comment: Try renaming the certificate file so that it ends with `.crt`